# Getting sub-classes from EntityManager.find()

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have a JPA entity that can be sub-classed, defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "IDTYPE",
    discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING,
    length = 12)
public class BaseObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    //etc
```

The benefit to this is that **BaseObject** and all its subclasses share the same ID field -- each value is unique to all of them.  My question is when I do an **EntityManager.find()** on the base class like this:

```
@PersistenceContext protected EntityManager em;

//  find a record.

BaseObject obj = em.find(BaseObject.class, longIDValue);
```

Will the **find** method return one of the sub-classes if it is using that particular ID?   Or will it always return just a **BaseClass** object?

Follow-up question:  Is this behavior consistent among the different JPA implementations?  (e.g. Hibernate vs. EclipseLink)

Comment: and what happens when you do it ? When I do that with DataNucleus JPA I get the correct type ... i.e can be subclass. Just like the JPA spec

Comment: @NeilStockton I am having trouble with my app so I haven't gotten to test this yet.   But even if it works I wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something implementation dependent.  I missed that in the specification -- if you can post a link to it I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: Are you sure that you want/need a super entity with joined inheritance? This will cause a critical slow down, especially on *@OneToMany/@ManyToMany* relations.

Comment: @MicheleMariotti Well the use case is this:  suppose the ID is part of a URL .  The servlet doesn't know in advance what class that refers to when it has to fetch it.  It may be BaseObject or some sub-class.   Once it has it we can then simply use instanceof for whatever logic it needs to serve an appropriate response.   So yes I think we do want the behavior that is specified.

Comment: Well, if that's your requirement I think you're right, no choice. Even using pure SQL can't think a better way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EntityManager.find()` returns an instance of the type for the specified "*id*" and entityClass. If you have inheritance and provide the superclass and the "*id*" implies an instance of a subclass then this will return the subclass (polymorphism). The whole reason why there are discriminators added to tables is to allow the implementation to provide such handling for you.

The JPA spec description of `find()` (not that they bother adding much description) does not *explicitly* state this behaviour, though it has to do as above to be consistent with a basic JPQL query "`SELECT b FROM BaseClass b`" which will return instances of SubClass where an object is of that type.